# WebBrowser.openAuthSessionAsync has a token in result?

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-web

Does anyone has any idea on how to get the token from
WebBrowser.openAuthSessionAsync(url, redirectUrl) result? or how to get the parameter data of it.

Thank you so much in advance.